# SQL Server 2000 and System.Transactions.TransactionScope()

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2000, transactionscope

Is it possible to create LIGHTWEIGHT transactions using TransactionScope() with SQL2000? Or if not, is there a workaround using CommitableTransaction and/or something similar?

So the answer is, basically, "If you want local-to-1-server-transactions on SQL2000, don't use TransactionScope()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightweight transactions require support for "promotable" transactions. SQL Server 2000 simply does not have support for this. Promotable transactions were added in SQL Server 2005.

Florin Lazar [posted an adapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/florinlazar/archive/2005/09/29/fast-transactions-with-system-transactions-and-microsoft-sql-server-2000.aspx) that can be used in specific scenarios. You'll have to judge for yourself if this adapter is appropriate for your environment.